# android:resources @xml is not available

Tags: android, xml, android-widget

when I use android:resource within meta-data tag and tried to get @xml which does not appear. I have included the code. Pls help. I am using API level 15 the target and API 14 as minimum

```
<receiver android:name=".widget" > 
   <intent-filter> 
    <action android:name="anddroid.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" /> 
  </intent-filter> 
  <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="here the @xml does not appear"> </meta-data> 
</receiver>
```

---

Comment: <receiver android:name=".widget" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="anddroid.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="">
            </meta-data>
        </receiver>

Comment: Found the answer. It didnt appear at the first place because I have not created an App widget provider xml at the first place.